# Autowiring a list of Java generic classes

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have an interface

```
public interface IType {}
public class TypeA implements IType {}
public class TypeB implements IType {}
```

And another interface of which the above interface is a generic type

```
public interface IValue<T extends IType> {}

@Component public class ValueA<T extends IType> implements IValue<T> {}
@Component public class ValueB<T extends IType> implements IValue<T> {}
```

And finally a class which uses these

```
@Component
public class DoThings
{
    @Autowired
    List<IValue<TypeB>> values;
}
```

Spring throws a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and doesn't seem to be finding the beans. What have I missed?

Comment: can you try with @Qualifier annotation along with Autowired, 
     Qualifier(TypeB.class)
     List<IValue<TypeB>> values;

Comment: In truth my actual problem has multiple generic types, I'm not sure how to qualify that.

Comment: A guess, but how about `List<? extends IValue<TypeB>>`?